# How to remove previous li on anchor click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am setting some `<li>` and anchor tag using jQuery . Now i want to remove the attach li on anchor click.Let me show on code what I am trying to do.And I can't assign any id to these elements as they are generating dynamically.

```
 <ul id="imagess">
<li><img width="60" height="60" src="http://example.com/images/event.png"></li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="deleteit('event.png')"> <img style="float: left;   margin-left: -25px;margin-top: 60px;" src="http://example.com/images/delete.png"></a>    
<li><img width="60" height="60" src="http://example.com/images/event2.png"></li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="deleteit('event2.png')"> <img style="float: left;   margin-left: -25px;margin-top: 60px;" src="http://example.com/images/delete.png"></a>
</ul>
```

I am trying to remove the `<li>` on `deletit()` js function call

Comment: show your deletit function...

Comment: Isn't that html invalid? Anchor elements shouldn't be direct children of UL elements.

Comment: That HTML is invalid! http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution for your current HTML using event delegation.

```
$(document).on('click', 'li + a', function(){
    $(this).prev().remove();
})
```

However, your HTML/JS should look more like this to be valid:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#imagess li a', function(){
  console.log(this);
    $(this).closest('li').remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<ul id="imagess">
      <li>
        <img width="60" height="60" src="http://example.com/images/event.png">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">
          <img style="float: left;   margin-left: -25px;margin-top: 60px;" src="http://example.com/images/delete.png">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <img width="60" height="60" src="http://example.com/images/event2.png">
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">
          <img style="float: left;   margin-left: -25px;margin-top: 60px;" src="http://example.com/images/delete.png">
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: thanks but my anchor tag is out side of `li`. while your answer work on inside.check my question .

Comment: @MahmoodRehman It is impossible for your anchor to be outside the li. Read the comments, your HTML is invalid. You can not have that markup.

Answer (score 0):

You have the jQuery tag, so here is an example with that:

```
$(this).closest('li').prev().remove();
```

Update: from the wording of question details and your comment, it sounds like `path` is the anchor itself, and that you don't want to remove previous `li`, but the container `li` itself, if so, change to:

```
$(path).closest('li').remove();
```

**Update 2**

Check this:

```
$('#imagess').on('click', 'a', function() {
    $(this).prev('li').remove();
    return false;
})
```

However, this is only for your invalid HTML, where the `<a>` lives directly inside `<ul>`. In correct way, the `<a>` should be inside the `<li>`, which I see is now fixed in another answer.

Comment: its not working on deletit function.My code look like this .`function deletefiles(path){
   jQuery(this).closest('li').prev().remove(); }`

Comment: In this code I assumed you are executing it in the click event handler not another function. You need to replace `this` with the anchor element itself.

Comment: I need to see your event handler, but basically: `function deletefiles(path, anchorElement){ jQuery(anchorElement).closest('li').prev().remove(); }`

Comment: path is a variable that contains string data.Do you think that represent the anchorelment ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('ul a').click(function() {
    $(this).prev().remove();
});
```

`prev()` gets the previous sibling to the `a` element, which is the `li`. `remove()` is pretty self explanatory.

Also, your HTML is invalid. The only elements allowed as direct children of `ul` are `li` elements.

Edit: The answers with "closest" given above will be correct if you move the `a` inside the `li`. People are assuming they're already in there as the HTML is invalid otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Update : remove inline onclick attribute from `a` tag as you have defined click event in code itself
Previous fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Lp88exqb/
New Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Lp88exqb/1/

You should not have `a` tag as direct child of `ul` tag, it should be in `li` tag and than you have to use following code to remove previous `li` on any click

```
$('ul a').click(function() {
$(this).parent().prev().remove(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Step 1
   Your HTML CODE has to be like this
   -------------------------------------
    <code>
     <ul id="imagess">
         <li>Img1</li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="deleteit(this)">Img1</a> 
         <li>Img2</li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="deleteit(this)">Img2</a>
     </ul>
    </code>
-------------------------------------------
2. Write a JS Funcion like this
-------------------------------------------
   function deleteit(obj){
       $(obj).prev('li').remove();
    }
```

Comment: DONT FORGET TO ADD JQUERY LIBRARY :P